# React - Display current time using useState, useEffect

Tags: javascript, react.js, jsx

I am learning about hooks, so I try to write code that display current time.

I had comment in each line of code the reason I write it. So:

1. Am I understand right?
2. Is there any bad practice?
3. What need to be improved?

```
import * as React from 'react'

function App() {
  // Define a state for keeping track of time
  const [time, setTime] = React.useState("");

  // Logic, computation to update time (which is side-effect) should put inside useEffect
  React.useEffect(() => {
    // Running side-effect when component mounted (componentDidMount)
    const myInterval = setInterval(() => {
      setTime(new Date().toLocaleTimeString());
    }, 1000);

    // Clear side-effect when component unmount (componentWillUnmount)
    return () => {
      clearInterval(myInterval);
    }
  })

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{time}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You may find this interesting/useful: https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `useEffect` will run on every render. Because you're setting state in `useEffect`, state will render on every render, causing loops of unnecessary renders.

To fix this, pass an empty dependency array to `useEffect`:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  // ...
}, [])
```

Comment: What is the loops look like? I inspect the page and see blue border blinking (render) 1 time/s only. I add `[]` and things are the same too.

Comment: Basically it will add a new listener that updates state an extra time every second. So after 10 seconds, it will render 10 times at once. That's probably not what you want, especially if this component gets more complex in the future.

Comment: What do you think about this argument: "useState only fires if the the value you are updating the state with is different to the previous one so an infinite loop is prevented unless the value changes between cycles." https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53715465/can-i-set-state-inside-a-useeffect-hook

Comment: That doesn't apply here in your original code because it has no dependencies. By definition it will run on every render regardless of your state.